# Cómo crear columnas dinámicas en MariaDB?

Tags: base-de-datos, mariadb

Estoy trabajando con MariaDB y tengo 2 tablas, la primera llamada "Departamentos" donde están los distintos departamentos de una empresa (Ventas, Almacén...) y otra tabla "Empleados" en la que lógicamente se encuentran los empleados y su departamento correspondiente, mi duda es si podría crear un atributo en la tabla de "Departamentos" que corresponda al numero de empleados trabajando en cada departamento, pero de manera dinámica (Añadir un registro en la tabla "empleados" y que aumente el numero de trabajadores en la tabla "Departamentos"). ¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Pues lo primero que se me viene a la mente es crear una columna `numero_trabajadores`, luego cuando insertes hagas un update a esa misma tabla `UPDATE departamentos
SET numero_trabajadores= numero_trabajadores + 1`.

Comment: ¿Y por qué ese cálculo debería aparecer en la tabla?, ¿no haría mas sentido que solo aparezca en la vista haciendo un sum?

Comment: Pudiera ser, pero como sabría en cual departamento sumar al trabajador? Es decir como se si el trabajador pertenece a un departamento determinado

Comment: haces una sumatoria de la llave foránea del departamento con el cual el empleado fue registrado y luego agrupas por el nombre del departamento

Comment: Más o menos capto lo que quieres decir, deja lo intento

Comment: No se guardan datos calculados, a menos que su calculo lleve demasiado procesamiento.. si no.. estas penalizando cada insert y update de la tabla de empleados con un SP que en teoria y con un par de buenos indices deberia tardar nada (inclusive aunque tuvieras millones de empleados, no es un numero que te impacte)

Comment: Casi olvido responder, si funcionó solo hice una consulta y listo jajajjaa